# Issue with Environment Variable Injection after Upgrading Angular from 14 to 16

Tags: angular, typescript

We recently completed an upgrade of our applications from Angular 14 to Angular 16. While most of the applications transitioned smoothly without any problems, we encountered an issue during the build process for a few of them. The build process completes without errors, but it appears that the correct values from our environment.prod.ts file are not being injected properly.

In our environment.prod.ts file, we have a variable that is supposed to be injected by Azure DevOps. This variable replaces a string with a number in the following manner:

```
export const environment = {
  // ...other variables
  id: Number('#{idfromazure}#'),
};
```

However, during our intensive debugging efforts, we found that this specific variable throws an error, indicating that it's "Not a number."

We've gone through the changelog for Angular versions 15 and 16, but haven't been able to pinpoint any relevant changes except for this one: [GitHub Pull Request #48720](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/48720/files).

We're reaching out to the community to ask if anyone else has encountered a similar issue after upgrading. Currently, we're attempting to come up with a workaround to inject the ID into the application without exposing it publicly.

At this point, we're uncertain whether this issue is related to TypeScript, Angular itself, or something else entirely. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you get if you print the ID and what's it supposed to be?

Comment: @JaDa then i get NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the way numbers and booleans were being handled in the Angular environment file was affecting the outcome. Surprisingly, a minor adjustment in the code fixed the problem.

Initially, the following approach did not work as expected:

```
export const environment = {
  // ...other variables
  id: Number('#{idfromazure}#'),
};
```

However, after some experimentation, I found a solution that worked, although I don't have a clear explanation for why it behaves differently:

```
const fixForNumbers = (s: string) => Number(s);

export const environment = {
  // ...other variables
  id: fixForNumbers('#{idfromazure}#'),
};
```

By wrapping the Number conversion within a separate function, as demonstrated above, the environment variable id was parsed correctly. It's worth noting that this solution seems to resolve the issue, although the underlying reason for this behavior isn't immediately obvious.

This fix might be due to subtle differences in how TypeScript handles the conversion of the Azure DevOps environment variable. However, without a more in-depth understanding of the specifics, this solution can serve as a workaround for those facing similar challenges.

In this specific use case, replace #{idfromazure}# with the actual environment variable value from Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Angular CLI 15 the environment files are gone, so you’ll no longer see `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` while generating a new project.

The fileReplacements configuration has been removed from the `angular.json` file. You can still use these files if you want, but they are not generated by default anymore: you have to manually create them and add the relevant `fileReplacements` configuration in the `angular.json` file.

There is also schematic command `ng generate environments` that will generate env files and update your `angular.json`

So, try to check your `angular.json` file for proper `fileReplacements` configuration.

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    ...
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer but we already have this in our angular.json file. We did a workaround where we wrapped the variables that need numbers like this const fixForNumbers = (s: string) => Number(s); and for some reason this worked and I am confused why it works